# sqlite trigger output

Tags: shell, logging, sqlite, tail

I'm trying to create a script that will act like `tail -f` but for sqlite files.
Thinking that triggers were the best answer I tried the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER "tailf" AFTER INSERT ON "my_table"
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM "my_table" WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
  END;
```

The idea being that on insert, it would print the new row(s) to stdout.
Unfortunately, when inserting into the table, I got nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, assuming I can get this to work all from the sqlite shell, would it still work when other processes insert into the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When SQLite executes a `SELECT` command, it just returns the data to the application.
It is the responsibility of the application to do something with the data (such as printing it in the case of the `sqlite3` shell).

Inside the trigger, there is no application that waits for the result of the `SELECT`, so the result is thrown away.
The *only* purpose of `SELECT` commands inside a trigger is to call user-defined functions that have some side effect.

In theory, you could define your own user-defined function to print something:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TRIGGER "tailf" AFTER INSERT ON "my_table"
BEGIN
    SELECT print(column1, column2, ...) FROM "my_table" WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

But unless you control those other processes, they will not install that function for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can run sqlite in a loop.

## Dobule reversing

```
while true; do sqlite3 /tmp/db.db 'select * from (select * from j1939 order by timestamp desc limit 50) order by timestamp asc limit 50'; sleep 1; done | grep -E
```

## Simple monitoring

```
$ while true; do sqlite3 /tmp/db.db 'select * from j1939 where id>(select max(id) from j1939)-50'; sleep 1; done

1621524|LOGIN1|838
1621525|LOGIN2|19
1621526|LOGIN3|839
1621527|LOGIN4|20
1621528|LOGIN5|839 (more...)
```

### You can filter results.

```
while true; do sqlite3 /tmp/db.db 'select * from j1939 where id>(select max(id) from j1939)-50'; sleep 1; done | grep -E LOGIN5|LOGIN3

1621526|LOGIN3|839
1621528|LOGIN5|839
```

### You can extract columns you need

```
while true; do sqlite3 /tmp/db.db 'select * from j1939 where id>(select max(id) from j1939)-50'; sleep 1; done | cut -d '|' -f 1-2

1621526|LOGIN3|839
1621528|LOGIN5|839
```

## Possible improvements

you could also consider adding this to `.bashrc`, 
so you could do something like

```
sqlitetailf /tmp/db.db j1939


1621524|LOGIN1|838
1621525|LOGIN2|19
1621526|LOGIN3|839
1621527|LOGIN4|20
1621528|LOGIN5|839
```

and 2 seconds after

```
1621524|LOGIN1|838
1621525|LOGIN2|19
1621526|LOGIN3|839
1621527|LOGIN4|20
1621528|LOGIN5|839
1621527|LOGIN6|20
1621528|LOGIN7|839
```